# Microsoft Access 2016 - Record Count

Tags: ms-access, record

I am currently creating a task management system in Microsoft Access 2016 and was curious whether it was possible to create a report or form to show the count of records, the part I can't do is add the record count of two query's. Both query's come from one table but both have different Yes/No property's. The aim of this is to Produce a graph of the comparison between these two results from the number of records.

Query One:

[image]

Query Two:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *DCount*:

```
RecordCount = DCount("*", "[Quote Won Query]")
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the Job! now on to my next problem with creating a Task Schedule/Gantt Chart haha